# Opencart fopen(/upload/system/logs/): failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I got this error in my opencart shop right after uninstalling an extension. The complete shop does not work anymore. It has not my own template and all php functions do not work. This error shows up:

```
Warning: fopen(/my_path/system/logs/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /my_path/system/library/log.php on line 6
```

This is the Log class:

```
class Log {
    private $handle;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        //this is line 6
        $this->handle = fopen(DIR_LOGS . $filename, 'a');
    }

    public function write($message) {
        fwrite($this->handle, date('Y-m-d G:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }
}
```

Looks like the $filename var is empty. This also reflects the not working php i mentioned above. The logs directory is 755 and i tried it with 777.

And a second error shows at the bottom of my shop:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/index.php on line 104
```

Have anyone experienced this error in Opencart 2.0.1.1? Google says, that this must be a common error, but I can´t find a solution.

Comment: you have to include complete path from root directory

Comment: DIR_LOGS is defined in config.php. It is: /homepages/6/d421894284/htdocs/opencart/upload/system/logs/. I just replaced it in my question. And this should be the right path. I have not changed anything

Answer (score 3):

this problem happens When the system cant create the storage folder which contains the logs cache and modification folders because of permissions problems ,some times the problem happens after storage directory transfer from the dash board , so to solve the problem you need to do the following

1. create a storage folder in the root of the application 
   `sudo mkdir storage`
2. set the new folder to 777 or 775 or **755** permissions `sudo chmod -R 755 storage`
3. create a storage folder in the root of the application 
   `sudo mkdir logs`
4. set the new folder to 777 or 775 or **755** permissions `sudo chmod -R 755 logs`
5. create a storage folder in the root of the application 
   `sudo mkdir modification`
6. set the new folder to 777 or 775  or **755** permissions `sudo chmod -R 755 modification`

Comment: logs and modification folders inside of storage folder not root.
The tree must be \storage, \storage\cache, \storage\logs, \storage\modification, \storage\session

Comment: No, DO NOT do this, you should never set folders to 777, as well as being insecure, many web hosts will actually block things if you do that. Folders should be 755 and files should be 644.

Answer (score 3):

the answer is simple , change ---->

```
define('DIR_STORAGE','/storage/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', DIR_SYSTEM . '/storage/');
```

and do that to config.php , and config.php inside admin folder , change both folders

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `$filename` for the log file is either not set in your admin panel or not being passed to the constructor.  Check in `Admin > System > Settings > Server > Error Log Filename` and make sure you have something set there.

If so, next step would be to check the main index.php and make sure the code is intact around line 68 which should be :

```
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);
```

Answer (score 0):

$filename is empty , Find the filename because it not exist.

```
<?php
class Log {
    private $handle;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        if (! empty( $filename )) {
          $this->handle = fopen(DIR_LOGS . $filename, 'a');
        }
    }

    public function write($message) {
        fwrite($this->handle, date('Y-m-d G:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->handle);
    }
}
```

check if $filename is not empty

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same problem and were able to resolve it by putting correct data in these two files:

1. config.php
2. admin/config.php

Please make sure that you have put correct entry for `DB_PREFIX`:

```
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

Comment: Hi Dieter Meemken, You need to make sure that you have put correct prefix before the data name.

We got the same error of -  Warning: fopen(/my_path/system/logs/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /my_path/system/library/log.php on line 6 - due to this wrong entry.

We put the correct entry and the error was no longer.

Answer (score 0):

This is Local Project Root here, but you can change your Server Path easily.

**Note: you can change to config.php and config.php inside admin folder both File Compulsory.**

```
define('DIR_STORAGE', 'D:/xampp/htdocs/opencart_project/system/storage/');

OR

define('DIR_STORAGE', 'D:/xampp/htdocs/opencart_project/storage/');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/...
```

try this. i've solved this error using the command.

Answer (score -1):

Is looking for the files inside your storage folder. Do this step by step

```
cd /var/www/opencart_storage/
mkdir logs
chmod 777 logs
cd logs
vim error.log 
chmod 777 error.log
vim googleshopping.0.log  
chmod 777 googleshopping.0.log
vim ocmod.log  
chmod 777 ocmod.log
vim openbay.log
chmod 777 openbay.log
```

reload your opencart site

Presto!

Comment: Again, DO NOT do this. Folders and files should not be 777, as well as being insecure, many web hosts will block them after this. Folders should be 755, files should be 644.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem. Immediately after the installation appeared in the admin:

```
Warning: fopen (/ my_path / system / logs /): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /my_path/system/library/log.php on line 6
```

Here is the solution:
Permissions on the folder with logs after installation, you can leave 755! The file is located at /var/www/my_account/data/www/mysite.com/system/logs/openbay.log need to put permission 777. After that, I left all the mistakes.

Comment: Permission 777 in the same folder must be put on files ocmod.log and error.log

Comment: Folders should be 755, files should be 644. 777 is insecure and may be blocked by your web host.